# why are my loops generating/returning the same values repeatedly?

Tags: python

i am trying to make a sumo wrestler generator. I have described a class Rikishi which has some attributes (only strings and ints)

```
class Rikishi:

name = ''
weight = ''
skillRoll = ''
skill = ''
rank = ''

name = generateName()
*some loops to roll for numerical stats*
```

i also have a list that will hold all the Rikishi objects

```
rikishiList = []
```

then i have a function to generate an instance of the class

```
def generateRikishi():
    rikishi = Rikishi()
    return rikishi
```

a function to display the attributes in the object:

```
def describeRikishi(rikishi):
    print(rikishi.name)
    print(rikishi.weight, 'kg')
    print(rikishi.rank)
```

then i have a function to fill my array with the Rikishi objects

```
def fillBanzuke():
    for x in range (0, 2):
        r = generateRikishi()
        rikishiList.append(r)
```

and then finally a function to loop through the rikishiList and print a number (just to help visual clarity in testing) and then print the stats of the Rikishi object in each element of the list

```
def describeBanzuke():
    for x in range (0, len(rikishiList)):
        print("#",x+1)
        describeRikishi(rikishiList[x])
        print()
```

then i call the two functions

```
fillBanzuke()
describeBanzuke()
```

and then i print the size of the list just to ensure that my specified # of objects is being appended to the list

```
print('size of rikishi list:', len(rikishiList))
```

the result i'm getting is this

```
# 1
Udagaje
234 kg
Komusubi

# 2
Udagaje
234 kg
Komusubi

size of rikishi list: 2
```

can someone explain to me how i can avoid having the same information in each element of the list? i'm not sure if my problem is occurring when i am generating the rikishi object or if it is occurring when i am trying to print the contents of the list. any advice would be appreciated. only a few days into teaching myself python from scratch.

thank you in advance for your time and energy

Comment: Any tutorial on OO programming in Python would show you what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Because your "attributes" aren't actual attributes of the object (that would be `self.name`). You can set real attributes of the object in the constructor:

```
class A:
    a = 3
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 5
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.a} {self.b}"

o1 = A()
o2 = A()
print(o1, o2)
o2.a = 7
o2.b = 7
print(o1, o2)
```